# Is it possible to move the view in a particular interval and also with button action

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, timer

I am developing an application for both iPhone and iPad. Here, i would like to load a url in the uiwebview, at ( 0.5) time interval. After finish loading of web view, i want to navigate to the next view. I have implemented this, by adding the navigation coding to [webViewDidFinishLoad:] and it works fine. Now, my client needs to add a button in the view to navigate if the user not interested to stay in the web view for (0.5 ) sec.

- Is i should use separate (selector:) action for after delay : 0.5 and for round rect button ?

  ```
   if it so, how can i implement this,
   I googled it, but could not find the solution. Any help appreciated. Thanks.
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for the responses. Here, i have implemented "NSTimer" concept instead of using "PerformSelector:afterDelay". Here is the code,

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(goToNextView)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: NO];  
    // here i have set the time interval of '5.0' and after that taking into next view.

-(void)goToNextView

{
     newtest15 *nt=[[newtest15 alloc]init];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:nt animated:YES];
  }
```

And i have the button at the toolbar which is also used for navigating to the next view.

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender{

if ( [timer isValid]) 

{
            [timer invalidate], timer=nil;

        }

    newtest15 *nt=[[newtest15 alloc]init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:nt animated:YES];

}

/* here, when the user wants to move to next view before the time interval of '5', and presses the button at the bottom, this action will be performed, it will invalidate the timer and navigate to the next view*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: 0.5 sec in the viewdidload method.
Then define a method that display alert message buttons stay out or leave the page. then do some coding on alert view buttons

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I am asking, if the user taps the button before (0.5) sec, the (button) action should take place and not the (afterDelay) function.

Comment: You could have seen the images moving in various websites, for a particular time interval it will change, and you observe that the "navigation dots" appear below the images, if the user click on the third dot, the image view will be displayed. Similar thing i am asking but in the iPhone.